# Protractor test always passes, if the spec is inside a loop

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

**PROBLEM :**

- With the below code in the ***CODE*** section , the `expect` block inside the loop `forEach` is always passing.
- Example scenario and its respective test report screenshot

  `expect('bt bt-primary').toContain('btn');`

[image: test report]

**MY REQUIREMENT :**

- I need to get the list of all buttons in any given page and i should be able to test for the custom CSS behaviour's through E2E test cases.
- This test code should be reusable across different pages test files.
- Have disabled selenium promise manager to use the `async/await` method.
- While i was trying to achieve this, I encountered the following issue.

**CODE :**

```
describe('Login form', () => {
    it('should navigate to page containing login form', async () => {
      await expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(
        'http://localhost:4200/#/login'
      );
    });

    it('should contain buttons with bootstrap classes', async () => {
      const buttons = await page.getAllButtons();
      buttons.forEach(async (button) => {
        const classAttribute = await button.getAttribute('class');
        expect(classAttribute).toContain('btn');
      });
    });
  });
```

**QUESTION :**

Can someone help me on how to solve this issue ? I need to get list of elements and test it in a loop page by page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each just fires of these commands and doesn't wait until their resolution

Use `for` loop instead

```
it('should contain buttons with bootstrap classes', async () => {
      const buttons = page.getAllButtons();
      for (let i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
        const classAttribute = await buttons.get(i).getAttribute('class');
        expect(classAttribute).toContain('btn');
      } 
    });
```